# Как заставить кнопку менять фон рабочего стола на PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, livewallpaper, qprocess

На [github](https://github.com/Francesco149/weebp) нашел статью как поменять фон рабочего стола на видео фон.

Код PyQt

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from script import Ui_MainWindow
import sys

class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mywindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
ui.pushButton.clicked.connect( ) #Что написать чтобы поменять фон?????

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = mywindow()
application.show()
```

На `github` суть была - прописать команду в `cmd`, находясь директории файла:

```
wp run mpv --wid=66566 Test.wmv --loop=inf --player-operation-mode=pseudo-gui --force-window=yes --no-audio
```

И фон менялся.

Можете подсказать как связать это и кнопки из PyQt,
или хотя-бы статью на гите с похожей программой?

Comment: А причём тут [tag:c]?

Comment: Скрипт отвечающий за изменения фона на с написан

Comment: Может импортнуть Сишный код в питоне и написать функцию, запускающую нужный метод из Си скрипта? (сам не уверен) или написать метод, который через модуль ```os``` например будет запускать cmd команды

Comment: Да это вполне возможно. Нужно прописать скрипт с открытием cmd и чтобы в ней автоматом запускалась команда на c. Запихнуть это в def и через .clicked.conect осущетсвлить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться классом [QProcess](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtCore/QProcess.html).

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from script import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import QProcess
import sys

class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mywindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.runWallpaper)

    def runWallpaper(self):
        process = QProcess()

        args = ["run", "mpv", "--wid=66566", "Test.wmv", "--loop=inf", "--player-operation-mode=pseudo-gui", "--force-window=yes", "--no-audio"]

        # Приложение 'wp' должно быть прописано глобально, либо к нему должен быть указан путь
        process.start("wp", args);

        # ИЛИ
        # process.start("<путь/к/приложению/>wp", args);
        # Ждем завершения работы процесса 10 секунд
        process.waitForFinished(10000)
        

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = mywindow()
application.show()
```

Comment: Благодарю вас за инфу. Извините что долго не отвечал я был занят

Comment: @olexxxi немного поменял ответ на более правильный )

Comment: Я нажимаю на кнопку и ничего не происходит

Comment: @olexxxi может быть видео файл не видит, или исполняемый файл, или еще что-то

Comment: Как это можно исправить?

Comment: @olexxxi найти ошибку, мне отсюда не видать

Comment: @olexxxi добавил `process.waitForFinished(10000)`  может быть в этом все дело

Comment: К сожалению не помогло